Azure Pipeline fails to reach nuget source after 3 successes in same pipeline
My Azure build pipeline runs each of my dotnet test tasks separately.  The first two always succeed, but the third one always fails with a NuGet Unauthorized error.  The super weird part is that if I reorder the dotnet test tasks, it is still the 3rd one that fails, so the issue is not the particular project.
Pipeline steps:

Use .Net Core 8.x (success)  <- this was 6.x before the issue started
Use NuGet 6.x (success)
NuGet Restore on entire solution (success)
Build entire solution (success)
dotnet test on 1st project (success)
dotnet test on a 2nd project (success)
dotnet test on a 3rd project (fail)

Failing task output:
Determining projects to restore...
error: Unable to load the service index for source [private visualstudio.com nuget source]. 

error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). 

##[error]Error: The process 'D:\vsts_agent_0\_work\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1

Further, this pipeline has been working for years.  This problem just started yesterday, but it has consistently failed the same way a dozen times, now.  The only major change to the pipeline that coincided with this issue is that I changed the Use .Net Core task from 6.x to 8.x.
Is there some kind of security logic in place for NuGet that is seeing this as a DoS attack, because it is accessing the same url multiple times, even though each dotnet test task takes multiple minutes, so they are not all happening at once?
What can I do to resolve this NuGet issue?
Update:
I added the "--no-restore" flag to all of my dotnet test tasks, since I already have a NuGet Restore task, and I am now able to get a successful build, but this still does not explain where this issue came from in the first place.
Also, I found another .Net 6 build in our orgainization that had failed on the same nuget source, so I'm not 100% convinced that the change to .Net 8 is the culprit, unless the .Net 8 build locked up the NuGet source, so that the other build failed.

You could try to add dotnet restore before calling dotnet test. Is the result same?

Network issues might happen from time to time, or even outages. Can you please edit your question and put the full dotnet commands you're running in the pipeline?

Also, are all the projects using packages from the same nuget feeds? Your error message indicates an authentication error to one of them. Double-check you're using the right feed in your tasks.

but this still does not explain where this issue came from in the first place. - in one word: networking. Issues like these might happen from time to time, ie. there might be Azure DevOps or nuget.org outages that might prevent you from restoring the packages. I've seen it happen many times in the last 5 years. The workaround to mitigate (mitigate, not prevent) is to do the restore one time (ideally), as opposed to every time you run dotnet build and/or dotnet test.

This looks like something for https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Some things that might help mitigate similar issues:

Restore packages and build projects one and only one time (if possible), e.g. for the whole solution
Add retries to your restore task

Some sample code (not tested):
steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Use .NET Core 8.x'
    inputs:
      version: '8.x'

  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Use NuGet 6.x'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '6.x'

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'NuGet Restore on entire solution'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
      # ... other properties
      retryCountOnTaskFailure: 3

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build entire solution'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--no-restore'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet test on project1'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: 'project1.csproj'
      arguments: '--no-build --no-restore'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet test on project2'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: 'project2.csproj'
      arguments: '--no-build --no-restore'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet test on project3'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: 'project3.csproj'
      arguments: '--no-build --no-restore'

Some details:

retryCountOnTaskFailure: specify the number of retries if the restore task fails due to networking issues, etc
--no-build: don't build the test project before running it. It also implicitly sets the --no-restore flag.
--no-restore: don't execute an implicit restore during build or when running the tests.

Recommended reading:

Task types & usage
dotnet build
dotnet restore


I found that if I use the --no-restore flag for every step after the initial NuGet Restore, my build succeeds, but why did this all of a sudden become an issue after 3 years of it never happening with this build?

@Eric 3 years is a long period, but remember, networks aren't reliable. These kinds of problems might not happen all the time, but they're not rare either. Lesson learned: the fewer network calls you make, the less likely you'll run into similar issues :-)

PS: don't forget to set the retryCountOnTaskFailure property of your restore task! Better be safe than sorry.

@Eric if my answer helped you solve your issue please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as the right answer. Thanks!

When using the NuGetCommand@2 task to run the 'restore' command, the task will automatically generate a temporary nuget.config file. This nuget.config file contains the following information:

The public package feeds (such as nuget.org), and the private package feeds specified on the task. For example.
. . .

<packageSources>  
     <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
     <add key="PrivateFeed01" value="{URL of PrivateFeed01}" />
     <add key="PrivateFeed02" value="{URL of PrivateFeed02}" />
</packageSources>


The credentials of the private package feeds specified on the task.
. . .

<packageSourceCredentials>
     <PrivateFeed01>
         <add key="Username" value="{Username}" />
         <add key="Password" value="{Password/AccessToken}" />
     </PrivateFeed01>
     <PrivateFeed02>
         <add key="Username" value="{Username}" />
         <add key="Password" value="{Password/AccessToken}" />
     </PrivateFeed02>
</packageSourceCredentials>



Then the restore task (NuGetCommand@2) will reference this temporary nuget.config file and use the credentials in it to restore the required packages.
However, this temporary nuget.config file might be only available for the current restore task, and also could get cleaned after the current restore task is completed.
In the subsequent tasks, when running the dotnet test command, if you do not add the argument "--no-build" or "--no-restore", the task first will try to restore the required packages again and then run build. But the task will not automatically generate the nuget.config file at this time. If a project requires the packages from the private feeds, since the task cannot find the credentials, it could return 401 (Unauthorized) error.

For your case, since you have added the NuGetCommand@2 task to restore all the required packages before the build and test tasks, in the subsequent tasks, you should:

add the argument "--no-restore" to the build (dotnet build) task.
add the argument "--no-build" to the test (dotnet test) tasks. The "--no-build" implicitly contains "--no-restore".

By this way:

The build task will skip the retore process and only run the build process. It will directly use the packages restored by the previous NuGetCommand@2 task.
The test task will skip the retore and build processes. It will directly use the output files generated by the previous build task.
This can avoid the same retore and build processes getting executed repeatedly, and can reduce the execution time of the pipeline job as possible.



As suggested above, if you have added the NuGet restore task, on the subsequent build and test tasks within the same job, you can add the argument "--no-restore" or "--no-build" to avoid running the restore process repeatedly.  @Eric
